# How to stretch google map to full screen (From the URL itself)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to stretch my google map to full screen mode.
several months ago, I found a solution to this on the internet, but I can't find it now.
The solution was to add some argument to the url itself, but as I said, I can't find it anymore !

Does anyone know how to stretch my google map from the url itself? what is this argument?
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real time example... 
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/geocoding-region-us

Code example 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-region-us

I think u need to set the map object div u r setting has to have height 100% padding 0 and margin 0

Thought of adding the actual answer incase if someone looking for this...

We need to add the following parameter in the url 
&output=embed

Sample url https:// maps.google.com/?&output=embed

Comment: The solution is the same as I want, but I don't want to use javascript.
The same result was given to me when I found some argument that you can just add to the url itself...(and thats my problem - I can't find this argument now...)

Comment: You don't need javascript... U just need to set the css... <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>... U want a different than this?

Comment: I think you are looking for this add... &output=embed in the url... U need to add? In front of & If there is no other parameters